# How can I change SKLabelNodes's font size regarding device screen size?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making an universal game. Everything looks ok, except some SKLabelNodes that are looking good on iPad and terrible on iPhone. I thought if I could automatically change it's size to smaller if player uses iPhone – it would be great! I know I can check iOS version like this:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        skView.showsPhysics = false
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Maybe I could somehow do stuff regarding screen size or device instead of iOS version with this code? Or how to do it other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making it device specific,  check the resolution of your screen with `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size`  This will give you the current resolution that you can work with, and then you adjust the font size based on it with `label.fontSize` or scale the layer based on the screen size with `label.setScale(CGFloat(some #))`where label is a variable of type SKLabelNode.  Doing it this way allows you to futureproof your app.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific on the first part? How should it look like? Something like `if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size == ??? { label.fontSize = 30}else ...` ? What should I put instead of `???` and if I understand you right in total?

Comment: //Assume landscape: `if(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < 480) {label.fontSize = 30} else if (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < 576) {label.fontSize = 32} else {label.fontSize = 34}`  You would use it like that

Comment: @KnightOfDragon  Got it! If portrait I assume I need numbers like 320 and higher, yeah? Thank you anyway!

Comment: yes, basically keep it in a range you think is best for your font.  You can create custom sized iphone resolutions in the simulator to test this out, because you never know what the future holds for apple, the 5 brought in a new resolution to the family, the 6 brought in 2 different sets of resolutions, who knows what is in store for 7

Comment: @KnightOfDragon I'm sorry to ask you again, but which numbers I need to split iPhone4 and iPad2 resolutions in portrait mode? I tried to use different numbers, but on a simulator they are always stay in the same range. I try `if (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < 321) { levelLabel.fontSize = 30 }else if (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < 770) { levelLabel.fontSize = 45 }else { levelLabel.fontSize = 50 }`. iPhone and iPad are using fontSize = 45 now. And I want iPhone to use 30. I can't figure it out

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I just had to add `else if (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < 770) && (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width > 700) {
            levelLabel.fontSize = 45
            print("ipad")`

It works, thanks again!